# Extjs Tab panels tabs change while previous tab is still loading issue

Tags: extjs4

I am using Extjs 4.1.2

I am having tabpanel with 2 tabs and on each tab click, there are components added in respective panels and data is loading in components from ajax requests and I am showing loading....... message till it gets load the data.

Now, if i have clicked one tab and respective panel is showing loading message in several components inside this but in the meanwhile, I have clicked on another tab then It is not showing the another tab's respective panel immediately. It waits for current tab's panel loading the data for all components then it shows the another tab's panel.

My requirement is that when clicking on a different tab then default should immediately abort the loading of the current tab and begin the loading of the desired tab and show that desired tab immediately.

please let me know how we can achieve this.

Comment: It would help if you showed us the relevant code. How are you loading the data in the tab panels? Is it asynchronous or synchronous?

Comment: yeah, It is asynchronous.... i am loading data using ajax service calls....